# Trying to use a font I have downloaded off the internet but not working

Tags: html, css

[the photo file name and file location](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T4Tdw.jpg)I'm designing a website for a nonprofit organization and I've downloaded a font that I would like to use, disclaimer it isn't from google fonts, and I have tried to use the font-face CSS code. Many tries and many videos later I am still stuck, I may have the name wrong from the file but I don't quite know what I have wrong.

```
@font-face{
font-family:vintage;
src: url('gonna getha personal use.ttf');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Per this (unofficial) [documentation](https://www.w3schools.com/csSref/css3_pr_font-face_rule.asp), it looks like you're close. you may want to ensure that your font file does not have spaces in the name. Additionally, make sure that you have permission to use the font-- personal use and nonprofit may not always coincide. Check the license for more information.

```
@font-face {
  font-family: vintage;
  src: url(fontName.tff);
}
```

Ensure that the font is hosted on the same server as the rest of the code, and that you're giving the correct path in the src.

Then you should be able to use it by specifying the font in a css file:

```
p{
  font-family: vintage;
}
```

or inline:

```
<p style="font-family: vintage">Words here</p>
```

Comment: I downloaded the font off of 1001fonts and it's for personal use and the fonts file name has spaces and I used that format before and it didn't work.